# How to get value inside the fancybox after the fancybox is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I noticed that the fancybox doesn't have parameter in close method, which I want to pass some value to that message so the 'onClosed' delegate can get the arguments info.

Also, in onClosed method, it seems use document.getElementById('xx') doesn't work.(xx is element id inside the fancybox)

So, how can I get some value ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code, the content of FancyBox is completely removed before the "onClosed" callback. So, no you can't get anything from the content unless you reverse this order in the code:

- v1.3.4, Line 962 - 964:

  ```
  content.empty();

  currentOpts.onClosed(currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts);
  ```